# Executing procedure in oracle without any parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the below procedure in oracle :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE usp_Templates_Load_TruncateRawTables
AS
BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TBLTEMPLATES_LOAD_OTHEROBJECTS_RAW';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TBLTEMPLATES_LOAD_NOTES_RAW';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TBLTMPLTS_LOAD_INCSTATEMT_RAW';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TBLTMPLTS_LOAD_BALANCESHEET_RAW';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TBLTEMPLATES_LOAD_OTHERBANK_RAW';
END;
```

This procedure does not have any in or out parameters and i was trying to execute this procedure as below:

```
Execute usp_Templates_Load_TruncateRawTables;
```

The other way i tried was :

```
Begin
usp_Templates_Load_TruncateRawTables;
End;
```

But both the times ,i got the error saying:

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

ORA-06512: at "TC_OWNER.USP_TEMPLATES_LOAD_TRUNCATERAWTABLES", line 8

ORA-06512: at line 1

How to execute this procedure properly to get the correct output.

Comment: The error is clearly saying that you are trying to drop a table that does not exist; this has nothing to do with the way you call the procedure. If you want your procedure not to give error if a table does not exist, add some exception handling

Comment: `TBLTMPLTS_LOAD_BALANCESHEET_RAW` and `TBLTEMPLATES_LOAD_OTHERBANK_RAW` are 32 characters long and `TBLTEMPLATES_LOAD_OTHEROBJECTS_RAW` is 34 characters long. So these are not valid Oracle object names. Unless you're using 12c R2 with its  long identifiers, in which case you should say so.

Comment: Apparently you're logging in as `TC_OWNER`. Is that the schema in which the tables named in your procedure exist? If not you'll need to include the name of the schema in your `TRUCATE` statements. Best of luck.

Comment: It was actually caused due to one of the tables being invalid in the schema,fixing which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution 1 - add owner/schema names

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TC_OWNER.usp_Templates_Load_TruncateRawTables
AS
BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE schema2.TBLTEMPLATES_LOAD_OTHEROBJECTS_RAW';
    . . . . 
END;
```

schemas can be different as long as executing schema has permissions to executed schema. I added `TC_OWNER.usp_Tem...` fro visual effect

Resolution 2 - execute as the owner of those tables

`connect schema2/password @sid`

execute

```
BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TBLTEMPLATES_LOAD_OTHEROBJECTS_RAW';
    . . . . 
END;
```